# Close Java subprocess when calling program exits/crashes

Tags: java, python, pipe, multiprocess, orphan

I'm putting together a multi-language system, but am running into issues with orphaned processes.

My code consists of a Python program calling a Java program, with piped communication between the two programs; the Java program is persistent, not just a one-off run. Everything is generally working, but I need the Java program to close if the Python program prematurely exits.

I *think* the best way to do this is to have the Java program close itself if it can't detect the stdin pipe between the programs, but I can't figure out to do this.

Relevant Python code:

```
javaInterface = subprocess.Popen(["pathtojavaprogram"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Relevant Java code; I want the program to exit if it can't read from stdin, but I think that some blocking issues with the readLine() function are coming into play:

```
String stdinStr = "";
BufferedReader stdin = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

while(true){
    try{
        stdinStr = stdin.readLine();
    }
    catch(java.lang.Exception e){
        System.exit(0);
    }
    //Do stuff with the stdinStr data
}
```

Comment: Seems like a reasonable approach. The pipe being broken might just result in an EOF in the Java process stdin. The Javadoc for readLine() says it returns null on EOF -- have you tried just checking stdinStr for null instead of catching Exception?

Comment: Have you tried making the Python program prematurely exit? Does the Java process stay alive with this code?

Comment: Alex: Checking for null definitely fixed it; thanks so much. I totally missed that in the Javadoc... I was assuming it threw an exception, not returned null. Feel free to post this as an answer so I can mark it as answered.

Comment: trutheality: The java process does stay alive with the code if Python prematurely exits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered in the comments by trutheality, but I wanted to mark this as answered.

The `readLine()` function returns `null` whenever the pipe exits, so checking for that allows you to close the subprocess properly.